# SPSS PROCESS macro

Tags: spss, mediation

I have a moderated mediation model with 3 IVs, 1 mediator,  and 3 DV. I can't find the right model in the templates provided by Andrew Hayes for his SPSS PROCESS macro. What is the correct model and what you suggest to do with several DV? Thank you!